# Javascript is called in IE and FF but not in Chrome, why?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, button, onclick, onclientclick

I have the following code below for a button on an aspx page.  When it is clicked it should call a javascript that will print the text in that div.  Everything works great in IE & Firefox but when it is tried in chrome it is as if the OnClientClick is not kicking off the javascript.  I receive no errors and it works in IE and FF now.

Below is the code for the button that calls the javascript.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnEULAPrint" Text="Print" runat="server" ValidationGroup="EULA"
            OnClientClick="javascript:CallPrint('EULA');return false;"/>
```

Anyone have any ideas or links they could share to point me in a direction?

Thanks

Comment: Can you paste the generated HTML for us?

Comment: Can you also paste the code for the function CallPrint.

Answer (score 2):

I have to ask, did you try removing `javascript:` from the attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Might be some source issues. Because Its work for me in Chrome